# Optimize vector scan in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have such a problem, that I need to subset by 2 columns millions of times. Therefore, I'm looking to optimize the time of sub-setting.

I see that even though a vector scan is as per the the data.table vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html a vector scan

> is automatically optimized to use binary search

it is still faster to explicitly write as the keyed subset is intended.

```
library(data.table)

flights <- fread("flights14.txt") # From the "Introduction to data.table Vignette"

setkey(flights, origin, dest)




system.time({for(i in 1:5000) flights[.("JFK", "MIA")]})

system.time({for(i in 1:5000) flights[origin == "JFK" & dest == "MIA"]})

system.time({for(i in 1:5000) flights[origin %chin% "JFK" & dest %chin% "MIA"]})
```

```
  user  system elapsed 
268.689   5.203   8.767 

  user  system elapsed 
200.481   6.370   6.489

   user  system elapsed 
261.194   3.981   8.518
```

My idea is to rewrite the following code so it optimized (the number of elements in my search vectors are variable).

```
flights[origin %chin% c("JFK", "EWR") & dest %chin% c("MIA", "ALB",)]
```

One approach to try to use the first key as much a possible is slower:

```
rbind(flights[.(c("JFK", "EWR"), "ALB"), nomatch = NULL], flights[.(c("JFK", "EWR"), "MIA"), nomatch = NULL])
```

Is there a way to do this subset faster?

Comment: Looks like CJ function is an improvement `flights[CJ(c("JFK", "EWR"), c("ALB", "MIA")), nomatch = NULL]`

Comment: I want to subset and then summarise the data by as many combinations of origin and dest as possible. In my problem I have already cornered the number of combinations I want to summarise.

I will try subset.data.table.

Comment: Re the goal to subset and summarise using many combos, see `?groupingsets` and related functions. If you write a concrete example (of the multiple subsettings and the summarization), someone could post an answer illustrating.